# not getting song files in my app after using flutter audioQuery

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, audio-player, android-music-player, flutter-audio-query

I've tried every thing to get songfiles on my app but it still shows nothing, here is my code below:

```
       import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

       import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

       import 'package:flutter_audio_query/flutter_audio_query.dart';

        class slist extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _slistState createState() => _slistState();
}

        class _slistState extends State<slist> {
        final FlutterAudioQuery audioQuery = FlutterAudioQuery();
         List<SongInfo> songs = [];

          @override
        void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllSongs();
  }

          Future<void> getAllSongs() async {
    songs = await audioQuery.getSongs();
  }

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: songs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            leading: Image.asset(
              songs[index].albumArtwork != null
                  ? songs[index].albumArtwork
                  : "assets/placeholder.png",
            ),
            title: Text(songs[index].title),
            subtitle: Text(songs[index].artist),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `getAllSongs()` inside the `initState` will (if possible) load the songs but not change the widget state, you have two options:

1- Add a `setState` after `getAllSongs()`:

```dart
Future<void> getAllSongs() async {
  songs = await audioQuery.getSongs();
  setState(() {});
}
```

2- Load the items inside the widget tree:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
    body: FutureBuilder(
      future: getAllSongs(),
      builder: (context, item) {
        // Null data
        if (item.data == null) return const CircularProgressIndicator();

        // Empty list
        if (item.data!.isEmpty) return const Text("Nothing found!");

        // Load items
        songs = item.data!;
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: songs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Image.asset(
                songs[index].albumArtwork != null
                    ? songs[index].albumArtwork
                    : "assets/placeholder.png",
              ),
              title: Text(songs[index].title),
              subtitle: Text(songs[index].artist),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Remember, to get most of the user information you need [request the permission](https://github.com/sc4v3ng3r/flutter_audio_query/blob/de65567fda5ae3c1b040170478f22d1a2c33e46b/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L4-L5)

Comment: the circularprogressindicator();, just keep rolling but doesn't bring out the song list